# Multiple HTML5 videos on screen lowers video quality

Tags: html, video

I'm working on a portfolio site, where I'm using the video tag to show videos on the site. Often I need to show several videos that autoplay on the same screen, and for some reason that makes the video quality tank, so the text is unreadable.

Does anybody have a solution to fix this?

```
    <div class="twoTwoFr">

    <div>
        <video width="100%" class="videoStyle" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="video/Clever/2.mov" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <p>Car Overview</p>
        <p id="greyText">
            We created one connected EV overview page, where users now could see all the EV models from different brands side by side, compare and filter them by key parameters.
        </p>
    </div>

    <div>
        <video width="100%" class="videoStyle" autoplay muted loop>
            <source src="video/Clever/3.mov" type="video/mp4">
            Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>
        <p>Clever as a Partner</p>
        <p id="greyText">
            In order to maximise these revenues, we had to be proactive about driving potential EV buyers to dealerships partnering with Clever. We introduced Clever products into the flow, educating Non-Owners about the cost and specifics of charging an EV where it is most
        </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

And the 'videoStyle' class just adds a border-radius.

[image: Here's what the quality reduction looks like. Open it to see it clearly]

Comment: Sounds like a bandwidth issue, which (in addition to the terrible UX), would be expected.

Comment: So the answer is to just not have several videos playing at the same time? Or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: I assume. Hard to say without seeing your setup. Have you tried from another computer? Please see [ask] and provide more information.

Comment: if you only play one video is quality okay? if so, the issue will either be bandwidth or CPU to play multiple videos. I'd recommend against autoplay, especially with multiple videos unless there's a really good reason both from a performance and usability

Comment: Yes, with one video it looks fine. So if only one of the videos play at a time, you would assume that would fix the issue?